# Android HTTPGet errors

Tags: android, http-get

New to Android. Trying to make a simple app to execute a httpget request to a certain site when a button is pressed. The buttons work and the toasts work but I get errors when the httpget is executed.  Thanks for any help....

Here is what I have:

```
package com.example.impdmxcontroller;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void Ch1on(View view) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {  
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ch 1 On!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    try {
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
      String getURL = "https://www.google.com";
      HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
      HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
      HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
      if (resEntityGet != null) {  
        //do something with the response
        Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }  
  }  

  public void Ch1off(View view) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {  
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ch 1 Off!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    try {
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
      String getURL = "https://www.google.com";
      HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
      HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
      HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
      if (resEntityGet != null) {  
        //do something with the response
        Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }  

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tell what kind of error you get?

Comment: at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1208)
 at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:388)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:239)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164

Comment: How do I do that? Thanks BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP get is in the main View thread. Two ways to deal with it. either create a new thread to run the network task or add these two lines in the onCreate() method

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy ourPolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(ourPolicy);
```